# Elasticsearch refresh interval when index is not searched

Tags: elasticsearch

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#refresh-api-desc) on refreshes says:

> By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second, but only on indices that have received one search request or more in the last 30 seconds.

What happens if the index that was not queried in the last 30 seconds? When does it get refreshed? If I for example write to an index, don't search it for a long time and then search it, will I get up to date results? When I write I get the results immediately on the first search, so I seem to be misunderstanding something.

Edit:
[I got this answer on the elastic forums](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/refresh-interval-guarantee/289125)

Comment: `Refresh requests are synchronous and do not return a response until the refresh operation completes.`

Comment: @ExploZe I've seen that but my question is whether I am guaranteed the index refreshes after a certain amount of time even if it's not searched

Comment: @krezno did you ever find an answer to your question? I'm looking into that as well right now.

Comment: @Jann I asked this question on the elastic forums and got an answer, I added a link to the question

Comment: Thank you! I somehow didn't find that thread when searching for an answer.